# Isolate references of included files within a "namespace"

Tags: cross-referencing, multiple-files

I want to compile a large series of mostly independent latex files into a single document, and I would like to be able to assume that each `\label` lives in its own "namespace". Ideally, what I would like to have is:

file1.tex:

```
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:a}
  a+b
\end{equation}

This is \eqref{eq:a}
```

file2.tex:

```
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:a}
  a+2b
\end{equation}

This is a very different \eqref{eq:a}
```

main.tex:

```
\include{file1.tex}
\include{file2.tex}

I would like to reference (with hyperref) both \ref{eq:a@file1.tex} and \ref{eq:a@file2.tex}
```

The purpose of this is to cross-reference and assemble a large collection of independent documents (but not to spend days doing so).

A solution in which the cross-referencing would work across multiple PDF file would suit me too, but I fear it would be a lot harder.

Comment: To prefix the labels from other files in a "central" file you could use the `xr` or `xr-hyper` package. To include the independent files, I suggest to compile them separately and include the pdfs

Comment: @samcarter seems like a starting point, I'll have to dig into that more. The xr documentation is, hmm, terse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example with `document.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:a}
  a+2b
\end{equation}

This is a very different \ref{eq:a}

\end{document}
```

you could reference the label with a prefix using the `xr` package (or `xr-hyper` if combined with `hyperref`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\externaldocument[doc-]{document}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[xr-prefix=doc-]{document}


bla \ref{doc-eq:a}

\end{document}
```

(the option `xr-prefix` is an experimental option of `pdfpages`)

Comment: The link targets the original PDF file (not the one included), but this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks !